# GAM Error: Error in model.frame.default- variable lengths differ (found for 'day_num')

Tags: r, data-science, data-modeling, gam

I am trying to generate predictions for covid cases using a GAM model. The following code works and produces a projection of US cases.

```
  US_data = covid_cases %>% select(United.States, day_num)

  head(US_data)
  United.States day_num
1             0       1
2             0       2
3             0       3
4             0       4
5             0       5
6             0       6

  end_date = nrow(US_data)+28
  new_data = data.frame(seq(1:end_date))
  colnames(new_data) = "day_num"

  US_gam <- gam(United.States~s(day_num,k=45), data=US_data)

#generate predictions

  US_predictions = data.frame(predict(US_gam, new_data))
  US_predictions$day_num <- as.numeric(new_data$day_num)
  names(US_predictions)[1] <- "United.States"
```

I want to apply the same code to any country I choose and therefore thought a simple function would be easiest. This function basically takes all the code above and wraps it up in a function.

```
get_df <- function(df,location, day_num){
  data = df %>% select(location, day_num)
  return(data)
}

projection <- function(df,location,day_num){
  data = get_df(df,location, day_num)
  end_date = nrow(data)+28
  new_data = as.data.frame(seq(1:end_date))
  colnames(new_data) = "day_num"
  country_gam <- gam(location~ s(day_num,k=45), data=data)
  country_predictions = data.frame(predict(country_gam, new_data))
  country_predictions$day_num <- as.numeric(new_data$day_num)
  names(country_predictions)[1] <- location
  return (country_predictions)
}
```

However - initially it failed at the data subsetting line, so I put the get_df as a helper function. Now it fails at the gam analysis:

```
US_data <- projection(covid_cases, "United.States", "day_num")
         Show Traceback

Error in model.frame.default(formula = location ~ 1 + day_num, data = data,  : 
      variable lengths differ (found for 'day_num') 
    6. model.frame.default(formula = location ~ 1 + day_num, data = data, 
        drop.unused.levels = TRUE) 
    5. stats::model.frame(formula = location ~ 1 + day_num, data = data, 
        drop.unused.levels = TRUE) 
    4. eval(mf, parent.frame()) 
    3. eval(mf, parent.frame()) 
    2. gam(location ~ s(day_num, k = 45), data = data) 
    1. projection(covid_cases, "United.States")
```

The error seems to suggest that data$day_num does not equal data$location length, but I can't work out why it would say that because they are the same length.

I've read the various responses on stack overflow and can't find any answers, and hunting around the internet has turned up anything either. I'd greatly appreciate any help!

To get the covid data for a fully reproducible example:

```
covid_cases <- read.csv(url("https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/ecdc/total_cases.csv"))
covid_cases[is.na(covid_cases)] = 0
covid_cases$day_num = as.numeric(covid_cases[,1])
```